# Upgrade from Server 2008 x64 to Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008

Is it possible to "upgrade" from Windows Server 2008 x64 to Windows 7 x64? If so, what are the gotchas? Any links to instructions on how to do this?

I know that Vista and Server 2008 share many features and so I'm guessing that this might be possible. I've been using Server 2008 as my desktop machine (mistake) and now want to move to Windows 7 x64 but don't want to go through the full machine install cycle.

Comment: This is exactly what I would like to do, but I think I might have to just do a clean install.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, moving from server-grade OS to a consumer-grade OS has never been possible in the Windows family of OSes.  There is no "Windows 7 Server", but there is Windows Server 2008 R2, which would seem the logical upgrade path from Windows Server 2008.  If you're just using your Server 2008 system as a workstation, and you want to move to Windows 7, then I'd say be prepared for a fresh install.

If you need a second opinion, MS also has the [Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/get/upgrade-advisor.aspx) available.

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2 is codename Windows 7 Server. For the record.

Answer (score 3):

You can't upgrade from the Server OS to the Desktop OS. Microsoft explicit check the upgrade paths and it will not ask to upgrade Windows Server when trying to install Windows 7. As already mentioned the logical path is to upgrade to Windows Server 2008 R2. This is to be released the same week as Windows 7.